# Problematic load of google libphonenumber

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, npm

I can't load the libphonenumber. I get this stack trace that I can't figure out.

The error occurs at the require line:

```
var gp = require('google-libphonenumber').PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
```

`number.js:1058
  throw a;
  ^
AssertionError: Assertion failed
    at new goog.asserts.AssertionError (...../node_modules/google-libphonenumber/dist/libphonenumber.js:1051:20)
    at Object.goog.asserts.doAssertFailure_ (..../node_modules/google-libphonenumber/dist/libphonenumber.js:1068:7)
    at Object.goog.asserts.assert [as assert] (..../node_modules/google-libphonenumber/dist/libphonenumber.js:1075:53)
    at new goog.proto2.FieldDescriptor (..../node_modules/google-libphonenumber/dist/libphonenumber.js:1553:16)
    at Function.goog.proto2.Message.createDescriptor (..../node_modules/google-libphonenumber/dist/libphonenumber.js:2069:22)
    at i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneMetadata.getDescriptor (..../node_modules/google-libphonenumber/dist/libphonenumber.js:2946:117)
    at goog.proto2.Message (..../node_modules/google-libphonenumber/dist/libphonenumber.js:1897:23)
    at new i18n.phonenumbers.PhoneMetadata (..../node_modules/google-libphonenumber/dist/libphonenumber.js:2411:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (..../node_modules/google-libphonenumber/dist/libphonenumber.js:4432:56)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)`

the google-libphonenumber version is 1.0.7 (latest) and it doesn't work with older versions either.
Please help!

Comment: Just tested out hammerzeit's library...it needs a lot of work.  I doesn't auto detect the country unless there is a leading +.  It will parse +1-800-012-3456 but not 1-800-012-3456 or 800-012-3456 unless I specify this is a US number...which I don't know...that is the point of using the library.